# What happened to python-networkx in 20.04?

Tags: package-management, python

The `python-networkx` package has disappeared in 20.04 (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python-networkx). Oddly, the `python-networkx-doc` package still exists. Was it renamed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that, yes, it was renamed: `python3-networkx`.